# ¿Cómo sacar todas las combinaciones posibles en pareja, con un rango determinado?

Tags: c, bucles, numberformat

Si el rango ingresado es: Mínimo: 1 y Máximo: 3, las combinaciones a imprimir serían: 1 – 2, 1 – 3 y 2 – 3.

Yo intenté hacer eso pero no logro agrupar todo.

Si se pone un mínimo de 4 y un máximo de 8, debería de sacar todas las combinaciones únicas sin repetir los valores, en este caso: 4-5,4-6,4-7,4-8,8-7,8-6 y 8-5.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  int min=0;
  int max=0;
  int k;

    printf("\n se realizara un rango, piense en dos números, uno será el mínimo y el otro el máximo, seguido se colocaran los números que estan dentro de este rango  \n");

    printf("\n ingrese el minimo: \n");
    scanf("%d",&min);

    printf("\n ingrese el maximo: \n");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    for (int k=min; k<=max; k++)
    {
     printf( "\n%d\n", k);
    }
    for (int k=min+1; k<=max; k++)
    {
     printf( "\n%d\n", k);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: No lo tengo claro, ¿cuál debería ser la salida si `min=3` y `max=7`?, sería excelente una explicación generalizada para un `min=n` y `max=m`.

Comment: Con tu edición la cosa está menos clara aún, una combinación posible sería 5-7 por ejemplo, ¿por qué esta combinación no entraría?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este es el resultado que deseas:

Tu primer bucle debería ser:

```
for( int k = min + 1 ; k <= max ; k ++ ) printf( "%d - %d\n" , min , k ) ;
```

Y el segundo bucle sería:

```
for( int k = max - 1 ; k > min ; k -- ) printf( "%d - %d\n" , max , k ) ;
```

Esto imprimiría: 1-2 , 1-3 , 1-4 , 4-3 , 4-2 .

Answer (score 0):

Basta con tener dos bucles anidados:

```
for( int i=min; i<max; i++ )
{
  for( int j=i+1; j<=max; j++ )
  {
    printf("%d - %d\n", i, j);
  }
}
```